# Commerce Feeds: Multiple values in one field or multiple fields?

Tags: database, feeds, commerce

#### Goal

What I'm trying to ultimately accomplish is create tiered pricing based on quantities.
The client is selling different prices depending on quantity. I'm trying to figure out what is the simplest way to store, access and represent this data using fields. While at the same time i'm importing them through [commerce feeds](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_feeds).

#### About my feed/data

I have a CSV table header with the columns "P1 Price," "P2 Price," and "P3 Price." There are also "P1 Qty," "P2 Qty," and "P3 Qty."

Thus, P1 Price corresponds to P1 Quantity, etc.

#### My question

Would it be simpler, in terms of less complex rules or views configuration, in the long run if i created separate fields to store each price/quantity, or if I combined them into one field that stores 6 different values?

My primary considerations include, scalability, maintainability, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an issue queue related to this: http://drupal.org/node/759966. Also,  currently multivariable fields haven't been implemented in feeds.

There's also a commerce price table processor patch currently being reviewed.

Randy fay also shows [how to utilize feeds_tamper to add multivariable fields](http://www.drupalcommerce.org/node/467) via a video screen cast.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you need is [commerce price table](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_price_table). There isn't a stable release for it yet, but I have seen it demoed where it worked great.

Answer (score -1):

Looks related to [Feeds support for importing prices](http://drupal.org/node/1274518#comment-6188606)